# OpenCV: linearPolar is not a member of cv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm having some troubles using the openCV linearPolar() function.

This is my code:

```
cv::Mat resImage;
        cv::Point2f center( (float)image.cols / 2, (float)image.rows / 2 );
        cv::linearPolar(image, resImage, center, M, INTER_LINEAR + WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS);
```

And these are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

If I try to compile, the compiler says "'linearPolar' is not a member of 'cv', but actually the function should be declared in the imgproc.hpp header.

Maybe anyone of you had this problem too and can help!

Thanks!
Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has been deprecated, as it produces the same results as `cv::warpPolar()`. I'm not sure which version you use, but maybe it's been taken out by now?

Anyway, I recommend you use `cv::warpPolar()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set OpenCV before, I have compiled like this:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/share/OpenCV")   
find_package(OpenCV 3.2 REQUIRED)
```